# Recursive solution for checking if 2 trees are identical: Is memoization possible?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I recently learnt about memoization, but the examples they used were functions to solve not so complex problems like Fibonacci sequences and factorials. I want to know if memoization is possible here, and if so how to apply memoization here since the recursive function receives multiple args and we are working with nodes

Question:

```
Given two binary trees, write a function to check if they are the same or not.
Two binary trees are considered the same if they are structurally identical and the nodes have the same value.
```

Sample Solution:

```
def isSameTree(self, p: TreeNode, q: TreeNode) -> bool:
        if not p and not q:
            return True
        elif (not p and q) or (not q and p):
            return False
        elif p.val!=q.val:
            return False
        return True and self.isSameTree(p.left,q.left) and self.isSameTree(p.right,q.right)
```

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memoization is only useful if an algorithm can possibly call itself to solve the *same* problem a second time, i.e. when the argument(s) are exactly the same as in some earlier call.

For instance, a recursive implementation of a Fibonacci function could look like this:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

The recursion tree looks like this:

```
                  fib(n)
               /          \
              /            \
          fib(n-1)         fib(n-2)
          /      \          /     \
       fib(n-2) fib(n-3)  ...     ...
        /   \    /   \
      ...   ... ... ...
```

We see that `fib(n-2)` occurs twice, and that leads to double work. Memoization will prevent the right subtree of the recursion tree to extend deeper: we already had called `fib(n-2)` at the left side of the tree, and so we can just use that value for the second time this call is made.

This cannot happen with the `isSameTree` function: every time it is called recursively, it will be with a different set of nodes. So memoization would not help to make the algorithm complete sooner.